# Manually manage join table association in activeRecord

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three tables, server, domain, site, I'm trying to make it so it works like this:

You create a site, then a primary domain and aliases and assign the primary domain to a site (by selecting a site via drop down box within domain page).

Then in the servers, you select a site and it auto assigns all domains for that site (including aliases) to that server.

The Domains table is also used as a through table for both the site and server tables

However at the moment, when you select a site and then save it it auto-generates the relation rather then using the one's that are already there.

Also for some reason activeRecord won't let me assign the domains to the server either, no matter how I try it:

```
server.domains = domains
server.domains_id = domains.map(:&id)
server[:domains_id] = domains.map(:&id)
server.assign_attribute(:domains, domains)
server.assign_attribute(:domains_id, domains.map(:&id)
```

`domains_id` on the server remains nil despite not erroring (it saves successfully, just `domains_id` is nil)

Ultimately, what I would like to know is how to manually manage the join table and also why won't rails let me assign values to the attribute?

server.rb:

```
class Server < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :set_domains#, if: :sites_id_changed?
  has_many :domains, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :sites, through: :domains
  has_many :projects, through: :sites
  has_many :clients, through: :projects


  def set_domains
    domains = get_domains Site.where(id: self.site_ids).all
    domains += get_domains domains,:domains
    domains.each do |domain|
      domain.server = self
    end
    self.domains = domains
  end


  private
    def get_domains(objects,meth=:domain)
      objects.first.blank? ? [] : objects.map(&meth).flatten
    end
end
```

domain.rb:

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord

  alias_attribute :aliases, :domains
  alias_attribute :alias_of, :domain

  has_many :domains, dependent: :nullify
  belongs_to :domain, optional: true

  belongs_to :site, optional: true
  belongs_to :server, optional: true

  def alias?
    !self.alias_of.blank?
  end


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :domains, allow_destroy: true


end
```

site.rb:

```
class Site < ApplicationRecord
  enum environment: %i{development staging production}

  before_save :set_server

  belongs_to :project, optional: true
  belongs_to :client, optional: true
  has_one :domain, dependent: :nullify
  has_many :servers, through: :domain

  def set_server
    self.server = self.domain.server
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't follow your question. As far as I can tell the relationship between `Server` and `Domain` is a standard N -> 1 relationship. There shouldn't be a join table. If that relationship is supposed to be N -> N, you've got a number of mistakes.